# Percent of Total for Categories Within Different Panes

Tags: tableau-api

I'm attempting to calculate the percent of total based off the the first column in each pane. However, table calculations only allow a calculation based off the each pane

```
SUM({ FIXED [Category]:SUM([Number of Records])})/TOTAL(SUM([Number of Records]))
```

does not produce the desired result.

It simply measures the number of records total in the category.

I cannot fixed the `TOTAL` function to category as it is a table calculation.

In the image, essentially I am trying to get all of the bars of the same color together without adjusting their heights.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYfH0.png)

Comment: I think some clarification on the calculation you are looking for is required here. Are you looking for the percentage of all Furniture Category comes from each Region? And the same for Office Supplies, Technology, etc? Or are you looking for a breakdown for each Region separated by Category?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure on what you're trying to do, when you say "percent of total based off the the first column in each pane" - does that mean total records with category 'furniture' & region 'central' shown as a percentage of all records, or total records with category 'furniture' shown as a percentage of all records with region 'central'? Or something else?

I have a feeling you can get to what you need by creating 2 fixed LOD calculations, or by fixing to 2 dimensions (e.g. { FIXED [Category],[Region]:SUM([Number of Records])}